# Running multiple SQL statements using Boto3 and AWS Glue

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3, amazon-athena

I would like to run multiple SQL statements in a single AWS Glue script using boto3.

The first query creates a table from S3 bucket (parquet files)

```
import boto3

client = boto3.client('athena')

config = {'OutputLocation': 's3://LOGS'}

client.start_query_execution(QueryString = 
        """CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS my_database_name.my_table (
          'apples' string,
          'oranges' string,
          'price' int
       
        ) PARTITIONED BY (
          update_date string 
        )
        STORED AS PARQUET
        LOCATION 's3://LOCATION'
        TBLPROPERTIES ('parquet.compression' = 'SNAPPY');""", 
        QueryExecutionContext = {'Database': 'my_database_name'}, 
        ResultConfiguration = config)
```

This only creates the table. Then I have to run the following query in order to update the partitions and insert the data.

```
client.start_query_execution(QueryString = 
        """MSCK REPAIR TABLE my_database_name.my_table;""",
        QueryExecutionContext = {'Database': 'my_database_name'}, 
ResultConfiguration = config)
```

Unfortunately, when I run the above statements in a single GLUE script, the partitions are not updated (only the table is created). I have to separate them in two jobs.

Is it possible to have a single scripts that can execute multiple queries in a sequence?

Using Glue Crawlers is not an option

Answer (score 0):

You should explore the alternative of using partition projection which removes the need of loading partition via repair table or crawlers. See the docs: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/partition-projection.html